# wordpress 4.7.2 email before download plugin sending mail but not showing download link

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress version 4.7.2. I have installed email before download plugin version 3.4.2 and download monitor 1.9.6. and the contact form 7 too. I have configured everything and it is working perfectly on my local machine.

The problem I am facing here is in my production server on the page when I put the shortcode [email-download download_id="1989" contact_form_id="1944"] and go to the page and fill up the form and hit the submit button, then it through a mail to email id what I have given in the form and then it stuck here nothing happen I do not get any download link here and when I open the browser console I am getting ajax post error what says 500 (Internal server error).

I have enabled attachment feature then in mail address I have an attached file and I am able to download it but when I click on the link what I get in email is showing an error of "Forbidden You don't have permission to access".

What I have missed I am not able to understand here could anyone help out.

Comment: Are the `download_id` and `contact_form_id` valid?

Comment: yes, I have checked it.